# VB.net SQL data reader needs tweaking

Tags: sql, vb.net, datareader

I currently have an issue whereby a 'using' sql query is returning a result where, if i access the DB directly doesn't

Here's my code for the datareader

```
    Using cmdobj As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select name from dbo.Cases where Case_Reference = 'AB-" & TextBox_Case_Ref.Text & "-" & ComboBox_ref_year.SelectedItem & "'", SQLConn)
        Using readerobj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdobj.ExecuteReader
            While readerobj.Read
                LIMA_OP_NAME = readerobj("name").ToString
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
```

Things have ony got complicated since we changed our case reference to 'AB-#####-YY' from #######

The problem is that, as long as the case reference exists, the resulting 'name' is returned correctly, but where a case reference doesn't exist, it seems to return the name of the highest numbered case anyway!

If i run the same query in my SQL management, it returns an empty cell...

I alreasdy have a 'If name = "", then error' type line, but it isn't working as the query 'is' returning a name - where it shouldn't be doing. Do i need some better error correction in there?

Additionally, for anyone who can assist, i want to pad out the entry in 'Textbox_Case_ref' to five digits with '0's so a user can simply type 1, 2, 3, and turn it into 00001, 00002, 00003?

Thanks

Richard

Comment: First of all, ***always*** use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx). As it is your code has serious [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability. Secondly there is [String.PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use to convert "1" to "00001" etc. About the problem: it's not possible that your where clause returns a row if column ***Case_Reference*** doesn't have the value you are querying, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Esko - thanks for the reply - I've fixed the textbox to only receive numbers as you weren't the first to identify the vulnerability. Fortunately i'm in an office where people would be unlikely to try such things!! I've been trying to use the string.padleft function, but keep hitting an error related to integers not be changes to string, or vice versa. Could you guide me with a starting point?

Comment: "Fortunately i'm in an office where people would be unlikely to try such things!!". You should **never** assume this. Believe me, you don't ever really know who your colleagues are. Besides, viruses can infect users' machines and browsers and attempt things the user might not otherwise try.

Comment: It's no extra effort to use parameters.  Why not close the security hole and completely eliminate the possibility?